# Combination of elements from multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm working on a chemistry research project and I need to create files for various angles. I want every combination of the following:

```
angle1 can be from [0, -36, -72, -108, -144, -180]
angle2 can be from [-180, -108, -36]
angle3 can be from [0, -36, -72, -108, -144, -180]
angle4 can be from [-180, -108, -36]
```

I wrote some Ruby code for this, but it appears to be giving me only half of the number of expected combinations. My programming skills aren't great, so I was wondering if anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you so much for any help you can offer:

```
phi1 = [0, -36, -72, -108, -144, -180]
psi1 = [-180, -108, -36]

phi2 = [0, -36, -72, -108, -144, -180]
psi2 = [-180, -108, -36]

psi1.each do |a|
  psi2.each do |b|
    phi1.each do |c|
      psi2.each do |d|

        line1 = 'select' + "#{b}" + '}}'
        line2 = 'select' + "#{a}" + '}}'
        line3 = 'select' + "#{d}" + '}}'
        line4 = 'select' + "#{c}" + '}}'

        filename = "angles#{b}_#{a}_#{d}_#{c}"
        puts filename
        puts line1
        puts line2
        puts line3
        puts line4
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Expected output would be 'puts filename' where filename would be every combination of phi1, psi1, phi2, psi2. I expect it to puts 324 times, but it's only doing 162 times.

Comment: not sure your requirement. can you add your expected output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-product) here.

```
phi1 = [0, -36, -72, -108, -144, -180]
psi1 = [-180, -108, -36]
phi2 = [0, -36, -72, -108, -144, -180]
psi2 = [-180, -108, -36]

phi1.product(psi1, phi2, psi2).each do |arr|
  puts "angles#{ arr.join("_") }"
  arr.each { |angle| puts "select #{angle}" }
end

angles0_-180_0_-180
select 0
select -180
select 0
select -180
angles0_-180_0_-108
select 0
select -180
select 0
select -108
...
angles-180_-36_-180_-108
select -180
select -36
select -180
select -108
angles-180_-36_-180_-36
select -180
select -36
select -180
select -36

phi1.product(psi1, phi2, psi2).count
  #=> 324
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like this. Your problem is that you overwrote the value in the same array when you did.

```
phi1 = [0, -36, -72, -108, -144, -180]
psi1 = [-180, -108, -36]

phi2 = [0, -36, -72, -108, -144, -180]
psi2 = [-180, -108, -36]
```

If you change the name of the second array that should fix the problem, I typed what I think you want.

```
phi1 = [0, -36, -72, -108, -144, -180]
psi3 = [-180, -108, -36]

phi2 = [0, -36, -72, -108, -144, -180]
psi4 = [-180, -108, -36]

psi1.each do |a|
  psi2.each do |b|
    phi3.each do |c|
      psi4.each do |d|

        line1 = 'select' + "#{b}" + '}}'
        line2 = 'select' + "#{a}" + '}}'
        line3 = 'select' + "#{d}" + '}}'
        line4 = 'select' + "#{c}" + '}}'

        filename = "angles#{b}_#{a}_#{d}_#{c}"
        puts filename
        puts line1
        puts line2
        puts line3
        puts line4
     end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm seeing that I'm declaring them twice. I'm declaring phi1 and pSi1 and then phi2 and PSi2. Since one is phi and the other is psi, shouldn't I be fine there? :S

Comment: you are correct, sorry it looks super similar and I missed that. I guess what  is the expected and actual output. It looks like it should be okay

Answer (score 0):

Why are you declaring `phi1` and `phi2` twice? I would do something like this:

```
phi1 = [0, -36, -72, -108, -144, -180]

phi2 = [-180, -108, -36]

phi3 = [0, -36, -72, -108, -144, -180] # this one now ends in 3

phi4 = [-180, -108, -36] # this one now ends in 4

# I declared a new, unique array for every set of possible 
# angle values

phi1.each do |a|
  phi2.each do |b|
    phi3.each do |c|
      phi4.each do |d| #I also made it so the for loops are for each individual phi 
                       #array.

        line1 = 'select' + "#{b}" + '}}'
        line2 = 'select' + "#{a}" + '}}'
        line3 = 'select' + "#{d}" + '}}'
        line4 = 'select' + "#{c}" + '}}'

        filename = "angles#{b}_#{a}_#{d}_#{c}"
        puts filename
        puts line1
        puts line2
        puts line3
        puts line4
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding how I'm declaring them twice. I'm declaring phi1 and pSi1 and then phi2 and PSi2.